# Regex to match group multiple times

Tags: php, regex

I want to match all occurences of "1x" and "2x" in combination with another non-capturing group ("WordX"). This is what I have so far, but it is only matching the last "2x":

```
^.*(?:Word1|Word2|Word3)*(1x|2x)
```

Test Strings:

```
Foo Foo Word1: bar 1x foobar 1x foo 2x bar
Foo Bar Word3: bar 2x foobar 1x foo 1x bar
```

https://regex101.com/r/zxfAB7/1

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As it is now, this is unanswerable. More info is needed.  None of your `Wordx` are adjacent to `1x or 2x`. If you just need to find the closest, it's something like `(?:Word1|Word2|Word3).*?(1x|2x)`

Comment: If what you really want is to match _all_ 1x or 2x after the WordX, you'd need to use the `\G` anchor. I'd show you how to do that if that is your intend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match all occurrences of `1x/2x` that appear after your non-capturing group, you can make use of boundary anchor `\G` here:

```
(?:(?:Word1|Word2|Word3)+|(?<!^)\G).*?(1x|2x)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zxfAB7/2)

`\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match.

Comment: you can shorten that to `(?:Word[123]|\G).*?(\dx)` to capture all '\dx's.

Comment: Sure that can be done for current example but it may be a example and OP might be using some different set of keywords in his real code.

Comment: @Marc `\dx` is not the same as `1x or 2x`. `\dx`  will match 9x too

Comment: Eh? and Yes, so it should be \d+x

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. Also Marcs hint about (\dx) is nice too.

Comment: Another thing: when using it in PHP with preg_match the results differ. When using preg_match_all it works, but I also get the full match as a capturing group. Is there a way to not return the non-capturing group?

Comment: Yes, you can use: `(?:(?:Word1|Word2|Word3)+|(?<!^)\G).*?\K(1x|2x)`

Answer (score 0):

***preg_match*** + **preg_match_all** solution to extract items (`1x` or `2x`) which only occur after last `Word[123]` occurrence:

```
$s = "Foo Foo Word1: bar 1x foobar 1x foo 2x bar";
$result = false;

if (preg_match('/^.*(?:Word[123]).*(1x|2x)/', $s)) {
    preg_match_all('/1x|2x/', preg_replace('/^.*Word[123]/', '', $s), $m);
    $result = $m[0];
}
print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1x
    [1] => 1x
    [2] => 2x
)
```